# displaying the value in another activity on clicking the value from the table

Tags: android

In android i have created a table with some values(string).On clicking of any value in the table the same value should be displayed in another activity.

I have created 2 activities.The first activity contains the table(using table layout) with values(String values all are textviews).Now On clicking of any value(I.e textview) in the table,the same value should be displayed in the second activity.I tried but i couldn't get output.is tat possible??

First Activity:

```
public class Table_LayoutActivity extends Activity 

{

      TextView textview;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TableLayout table=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
        table.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {

                        String value=((TextView)v).getText().toString();
                        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Selected_Item_Activity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("value", value);
                        startActivity(intent);
                  }
            });
    }
}
```

second activity:

```
public class Selected_Item_Activity extends Activity 
{
                @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selected_item);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String value=intent.getStringExtra("value");
        TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        text.setText(value);

    }
}
```

---

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to 
start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.tablelayout/com.tablelayout.Selected_Item_Activity}:java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #7: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:467)java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #7: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:3592)android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:3672)android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1395)android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1321)android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:45)android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:620)android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
com.tablelayout.Selected_Item_Activity.onCreate(Selected_Item_Activity.java:12)android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Comment: Actually i have tried like this...i got the table but on clicking any of the value the app is getting force closed.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting (check stacktrace from logcat)? Have you defined second activity in Manifest?

Comment: Yes, I have defined it.

Comment: LogCat: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableLayout,at com.tablelayout.Table_LayoutActivity$1.onClick(Table_LayoutActivity.java:23) at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408) :at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816) :at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) :at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) :at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) :at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) :at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

Comment: you are accessing a cell in a wrong way. This line is wrong:     **String value=((TextView)v).getText().toString();**

Comment: so wat has to be done??

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your snippet is that when you use `String value=((TextView)v).getText().toString();` you get **`ClassCastException`** since **`v`** is actually **TableLayout** itself and you are trying to cast it to **TextView**.

---

1) Solution suitable for TableLayout with only ONE column

---

So now we would like to get value from a cell in **TableLayout**. For that you do not have to set **onClickListener** on the component itself, but rather you can do it like that:

- in xml definition of your layout (*I assume you have something similar there now*):

  ```
  <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
          android:tag="1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:onClick="rowClicked" >

  <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:text="Row 1"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
          android:tag="2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:onClick="rowClicked" >

      <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView2"
              android:text="Row 2"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
  </TableRow>
  ```

> Here I set `tag` property to every **TableRow**, which is string and `onClick` event, which can also be set in your Activity that has this layout as its *content view* by using `setOnClickListener(..)`

- now in Activity that has this ^^ xml layout as its content view (which does this:

> ```
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.name_of_this^^_layout);
> ```

), you implement method `rowClicked`, which will intercept click events made on **TableRow** component:

```
public void rowClicked(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Selected_Item_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("value", ""+v.getTag());
            //or intent.putExtra("value", ""+((TextView)((TableRow)v).getChildAt(0)).getText());
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

---

2) Solution suitable for TableLayout with more than one column

---

- In xml definition of your layout:

  ```
  <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:tag="1">

      <TextView
              android:text="Column 1.1"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

      <TextView
              android:text="Column 1.2"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

      <TextView
              android:text="Column 1.3"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:tag="2">

      <TextView
              android:text="Column 2.1"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

      <TextView
              android:text="Column 2.2"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
      <TextView
              android:text="Column 2.3"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:tag="3">

      <TextView
              android:text="Column 3.1"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

      <TextView
              android:text="Column 3.2"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
      <TextView
              android:text="Column 3.3"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
  </TableRow>
  ```

Here every `TableRow` gets a tag, which must start from 1 and be incremented with every row (based on this solution)

- now in Activity that has this ^^ xml layout as its content view:

> ```
> TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
> TableRow row1 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow3);
> TableRow row2 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow4);
> TableRow row3 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow5);
> row1.setOnTouchListener(this);
> row2.setOnTouchListener(this);
> row3.setOnTouchListener(this);
> ```

```
private boolean containsCoordinates(int index, View view, int rx, int ry) {
    int[] l = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(l);
    int x = l[0];
    int y = l[1];
    int w = view.getWidth();
    int h = view.getHeight();

    if(new Rect(x, (y-h-(h*index)), (x+w), y).contains(rx, ry)){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ((TableRow)view).getChildCount(); i++){
        if(containsCoordinates(Integer.parseInt(((TableRow)view).getTag().toString()), ((TableRow)view).getChildAt(i), (int)motionEvent.getX(), (int)motionEvent.getY())){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Selected_Item_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("value", ""+((TextView)((TableRow)view).getChildAt(i)).getText());
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And do not forget that your activity has to implement View.OnTouchListener

Comment: Okay...let me try this and tell u... Thanks a lot:):):)

Comment: @user2523879 it works well for me, tell me what your logcat says?

Comment: @user2523879 Regarding your `logcats` stacktrace, i suggest you going through all your components defined in XML files and make sure to add to every component properties: `layout_height` and `layout_width`. That is exactly what your stacktrace says: `You must supply a layout_width attribute.`

Comment: it works fine for a table with a single column.Now, i have added another column so totally 2 rows and 2 columns.how it will work here.i have set tags for each text view in the table but i couldn't retrieve it.What has to be done in this case?

Comment: @user2523879 edited my answer with an additional solution for cases when there are many columns

Answer (score 0):

Don't put onClickListener for the entire table.

```
String value=((TextView)v).getText().toString();
```

In this line you are casting the View you clicked to `TextView`. If you click on any other view other than `TextView`, it shows **ClassCastException**.

So, you provide `OnClickListener` only to the `TextView` which you would click.